# Reinitiate Gutenburg's blocks using javascript

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that manipulates some Gutenberg blocks using javascript.

For better understanding, create a table in a post and run the code below in the console:

```js
let tableHtml = document.querySelector(".wp-block-table").innerHTML;
document.querySelector(".wp-block-table").innerHTML = tableHtml;
```

I'm replacing the `innerHTML` of a block, and then if I try to change the table caption or delete the table, it won't work.

and I think it's because the table is changed and the `eventListeners` are all gone so I need to initialize them again, but I don't know how.

I think I found the function responsible for that,  it's `table_init` located on `wp-includes/js/dist/block-library.js` but I don't know how to use it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Generally this is not the way you should interact with blocks in the block editor. Blocks are little React applications and if you manipulate them with outside JavaScript things are bound to break. What actions are you performing and under what conditions?

Comment: I'm making a little spellchecking plugin, is there any other ways to manipulate blocks without breaking them?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. What are you trying to manipulate? It seems like you want to change the entire HTML contents. What are you changing about the HTML? Also, it's probably worth noting that the editor already supports the browser's spellcheck capabilities.

Comment: yeah I manipulate the HTML and it's not only spellchecking, it'll be grammar checking too.